# STM32F042K6: region `FLASH' overflowed by 1212 bytes

Tags: c, nucleo, stm32cubeide, stm32f0, stm32cubemx

I am trying to program STM32F042K6 nucleo using CubeIDE and STM32 HAL but the compiler throws an error:

region `FLASH' overflowed by 1212 bytes.

Here is the exact console output:

```
09:55:03 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Virtual Com Port ****
make -j16 all 
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o "Virtual Com Port.elf" @"objects.list"   -mcpu=cortex-m0 -T"C:\Users\EE Engineering\Documents\Projects\Firmware\Virtual Comm Port\STM32F042K6TX_FLASH.ld" --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map="Virtual Com Port.map" -Wl,--gc-sections -static --specs=nano.specs -mfloat-abi=soft -mthumb -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group
c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.7.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.9-2020-q2-update.win32_2.0.0.202105311346\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: Virtual Com Port.elf section `.text' will not fit in region `FLASH'
c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.7.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.9-2020-q2-update.win32_2.0.0.202105311346\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: region `FLASH' overflowed by 1212 bytes
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:69: Virtual Com Port.elf] Error 1
"make -j16 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

09:55:04 Build Failed. 3 errors, 0 warnings. (took 340ms).
```

However, when I look at the memory regions in the build analyzer, it shows 16.58 KB free out of 32KB size for a usage of 48.19%. If only 48% of the flash storage is used, then how is the flash overflowing by 1212 bytes and what can I do to fix this?

[image: Build Analyzer]

Comment: You may check that the FLASH size is set correctly in `STM32F042K6TX_FLASH.ld`. I do not know which analyser you are referring to, but it may show only part of the program size. Try building with Release configuration instead. The Debug configuration has significant overhead.

Comment: Switching release configuration worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue and adding these compile options resolved the problem for me

```
add_compile_options(
     -mcpu=${STM32_PROJECT_CPU} 
     -mtune=cortex-m0 -g -ggdb -Os -g3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 
     -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -flto
     -std=gnu99 ${STM32_MFLOAT_ABI} --specs=nano.specs -mthumb -Wall -Werror
)
```

Comment: Adding `-Wall` resolved the problem?